# Display results from databound dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I have made a dropdown list named *Company Dropdown* that is databound. The dropdown's data comes from the sql database.

There is a table called *CompanyList*. Once someone selects a company from the dropdown, it displays *MemberType value*, *Membership Status* and *Reports* the company has access to.

So basically the dropdown acts as an *event* to whichever item is selected. That selected item shows the following results:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="28px" style="margin-left: 6px" Width="462px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyID"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
    <Items>
   <asp:ListItem Value="" />
```

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ds17701ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyID], [CompanyName], [MemberTypeID], [MembershipStatus], [GroupID], [Valid], [Ablaze_CompanyID] FROM [CompanyList] ORDER BY [CompanyName] "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My problem is: do I set up at markup, or program it on aspx.vb and if so, how do I code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an event on the dropdownlist (selectedItem I think) and then take the value passed in to the event and use that to refresh (databind()) another control that may have a list of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To display results from a databound dropdownlist, there needs to be a tool that can output data from the ddl, such as a gridview, datagrid, table, or some tool that can hold and output data. From the tool, the datasource must be the ddl, so that when a company is selected, the data of said company and its selected columns appear on said graphic.